# Using public key from authorized_keys with Java security

Tags: java, security, openssh

How can I use an entry from the systems `authorized_keys` file for a `java.security.PublicKey` implementation? I specifically want to compare a public key from the authorized_keys file with a public key available in the Apache SSHD `PublickeyAuthenticator` interface.

Comment: You may also want to ask this on the Mina mailing list.  This is a very good question, as this is one of the few missing components for a secure Java sshd implementation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was surprised there's nothing apparent out there for this. I got curious and implemented a way to decode `authorized_keys` files. This depends on Apache Commons Codec for Base64 decoding.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.DSAPublicKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class AuthorizedKeysDecoder {
    private byte[] bytes;
    private int pos;

    public PublicKey decodePublicKey(String keyLine) throws Exception {
        bytes = null;
        pos = 0;

        // look for the Base64 encoded part of the line to decode
        // both ssh-rsa and ssh-dss begin with "AAAA" due to the length bytes
        for (String part : keyLine.split(" ")) {
            if (part.startsWith("AAAA")) {
                bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(part);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (bytes == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("no Base64 part to decode");
        }

        String type = decodeType();
        if (type.equals("ssh-rsa")) {
            BigInteger e = decodeBigInt();
            BigInteger m = decodeBigInt();
            RSAPublicKeySpec spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e);
            return KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(spec);
        } else if (type.equals("ssh-dss")) {
            BigInteger p = decodeBigInt();
            BigInteger q = decodeBigInt();
            BigInteger g = decodeBigInt();
            BigInteger y = decodeBigInt();
            DSAPublicKeySpec spec = new DSAPublicKeySpec(y, p, q, g);
            return KeyFactory.getInstance("DSA").generatePublic(spec);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown type " + type);
        }
    }

    private String decodeType() {
        int len = decodeInt();
        String type = new String(bytes, pos, len);
        pos += len;
        return type;
    }

    private int decodeInt() {
        return ((bytes[pos++] & 0xFF) << 24) | ((bytes[pos++] & 0xFF) << 16)
                | ((bytes[pos++] & 0xFF) << 8) | (bytes[pos++] & 0xFF);
    }

    private BigInteger decodeBigInt() {
        int len = decodeInt();
        byte[] bigIntBytes = new byte[len];
        System.arraycopy(bytes, pos, bigIntBytes, 0, len);
        pos += len;
        return new BigInteger(bigIntBytes);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AuthorizedKeysDecoder decoder = new AuthorizedKeysDecoder();
        File file = new File("authorized_keys");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\n");
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(decoder.decodePublicKey(scanner.next()));
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to add the commons library as a dependency just for that. Take a look at DatatypeConverter#parseBase64Binary http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseBase64Binary(java.lang.String)

Comment: Would give 5 ups if possible! Thanks a lot for this!

Comment: For `ecdsa-sha2-*` keys, I've posted an update to the above code that adds support for them in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808132/using-openssh-public-key-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-with-java-security/44907432#44907432

Answer (score 7):

If you want reverse the process, i.e. encode a `PublicKey` Java object to a Linux `authorized_keys` entry format, one can use this code:

```
    /**
     * Encode PublicKey (DSA or RSA encoded) to authorized_keys like string
     *
     * @param publicKey DSA or RSA encoded
     * @param user username for output authorized_keys like string
     * @return authorized_keys like string
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static String encodePublicKey(PublicKey publicKey, String user)
            throws IOException {
        String publicKeyEncoded;
        if(publicKey.getAlgorithm().equals("RSA")){
            RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) publicKey;
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteOs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(byteOs);
            dos.writeInt("ssh-rsa".getBytes().length);
            dos.write("ssh-rsa".getBytes());
            dos.writeInt(rsaPublicKey.getPublicExponent().toByteArray().length);
            dos.write(rsaPublicKey.getPublicExponent().toByteArray());
            dos.writeInt(rsaPublicKey.getModulus().toByteArray().length);
            dos.write(rsaPublicKey.getModulus().toByteArray());
            publicKeyEncoded = new String(
                    Base64.encodeBase64(byteOs.toByteArray()));
            return "ssh-rsa " + publicKeyEncoded + " " + user;
        }
        else if(publicKey.getAlgorithm().equals("DSA")){
            DSAPublicKey dsaPublicKey = (DSAPublicKey) publicKey;
            DSAParams dsaParams = dsaPublicKey.getParams();

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteOs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(byteOs);
            dos.writeInt("ssh-dss".getBytes().length);
            dos.write("ssh-dss".getBytes());
            dos.writeInt(dsaParams.getP().toByteArray().length);
            dos.write(dsaParams.getP().toByteArray());
            dos.writeInt(dsaParams.getQ().toByteArray().length);
            dos.write(dsaParams.getQ().toByteArray());
            dos.writeInt(dsaParams.getG().toByteArray().length);
            dos.write(dsaParams.getG().toByteArray());
            dos.writeInt(dsaPublicKey.getY().toByteArray().length);
            dos.write(dsaPublicKey.getY().toByteArray());
            publicKeyEncoded = new String(
                    Base64.encodeBase64(byteOs.toByteArray()));
            return "ssh-dss " + publicKeyEncoded + " " + user;
        }
        else{
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Unknown public key encoding: " + publicKey.getAlgorithm());
        }
    }
```

Comment: how do you know the way to consturct this? Any references documents could share? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The same solution but delegates the decodeInt() to the DataInputStream.
I remove from the original code the BouncyCastleProvider for the KeyFactory as soon as it already knows the RSA algorithm.

Original source : https://github.com/ragnar-johannsson/CloudStack/blob/master/utils/src/com/cloud/utils/crypt/RSAHelper.java

```
private static RSAPublicKey readKey(String key) throws Exception {
    // key = "ssh-rsa <myBase64key> <email>"
    byte[] encKey = Base64.decodeBase64(key.split(" ")[1]);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(encKey));

    byte[] header = readElement(dis);
    String pubKeyFormat = new String(header);
    if (!pubKeyFormat.equals("ssh-rsa"))
    throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported format");

    byte[] publicExponent = readElement(dis);
    byte[] modulus = readElement(dis);

    KeySpec spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger(modulus), new BigInteger(publicExponent));
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);

    return pubKey;
}

private static byte[] readElement(DataInput dis) throws IOException {
    int len = dis.readInt();
    byte[] buf = new byte[len];
    dis.readFully(buf);
    return buf;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! After hours of banging against this, your code made sense to me and resolved the issue! Great idea with the `readElement` method.

Answer (score 2):

To WhiteFang34,

Your code is awesome and useful for me too, but it has a tiny bug.
Base64.decodeBase64 method receives only byte array. So I fixed like this.

```
    for (String part : keyLine.split(" ")) {
        if (part.startsWith("AAAA")) {
            byte [] bytePart = part.getBytes();
            bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(bytePart);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Anyway, thanks for writing code. I hope you to upload this code to github or elsewhere, or to allow me uploading into my github repos.

Comment: It looks like it depends on which `Base64` class you're using. The one included with Commons Codec 1.4 and later has the method I used: [`decodeBase64(java.lang.String)`](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#decodeBase64(java.lang.String))