# How to do I convert the PublicKey to OpenSSH authorized_keys format

Tags: java, bouncycastle, ssh-keys, public-key, authorized-keys

Here is the code to get the public key. I need to convert the public key to OpenSSH format to add it to the `authorized_keys` file in Linux. How can I do that?

```
KeyPairGenerator kpGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA", "BC");
kpGen.initialize(1024, new SecureRandom());
KeyPair keypair = kpGen.generateKeyPair();
```

I did use `PEMWriter`. But it didn't give the output string in proper format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@gotoalberto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3531506/850848#14582408) for a different question:

> If you want reverse the process, i.e. encode a `PublicKey` Java object
>   to a Linux `authorized_keys` entry format, one can use this code:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Encode PublicKey (DSA or RSA encoded) to authorized_keys like string
>  *
>  * @param publicKey DSA or RSA encoded
>  * @param user username for output authorized_keys like string
>  * @return authorized_keys like string
>  * @throws IOException
>  */
> public static String encodePublicKey(PublicKey publicKey, String user)
>         throws IOException {
>     String publicKeyEncoded;
>     if(publicKey.getAlgorithm().equals("RSA")){
>         RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) publicKey;
>         ByteArrayOutputStream byteOs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>         DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(byteOs);
>         dos.writeInt("ssh-rsa".getBytes().length);
>         dos.write("ssh-rsa".getBytes());
>         dos.writeInt(rsaPublicKey.getPublicExponent().toByteArray().length);
>         dos.write(rsaPublicKey.getPublicExponent().toByteArray());
>         dos.writeInt(rsaPublicKey.getModulus().toByteArray().length);
>         dos.write(rsaPublicKey.getModulus().toByteArray());
>         publicKeyEncoded = new String(
>                 Base64.encodeBase64(byteOs.toByteArray()));
>         return "ssh-rsa " + publicKeyEncoded + " " + user;
>     }
>     else if(publicKey.getAlgorithm().equals("DSA")){
>         DSAPublicKey dsaPublicKey = (DSAPublicKey) publicKey;
>         DSAParams dsaParams = dsaPublicKey.getParams();
>
>         ByteArrayOutputStream byteOs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>         DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(byteOs);
>         dos.writeInt("ssh-dss".getBytes().length);
>         dos.write("ssh-dss".getBytes());
>         dos.writeInt(dsaParams.getP().toByteArray().length);
>         dos.write(dsaParams.getP().toByteArray());
>         dos.writeInt(dsaParams.getQ().toByteArray().length);
>         dos.write(dsaParams.getQ().toByteArray());
>         dos.writeInt(dsaParams.getG().toByteArray().length);
>         dos.write(dsaParams.getG().toByteArray());
>         dos.writeInt(dsaPublicKey.getY().toByteArray().length);
>         dos.write(dsaPublicKey.getY().toByteArray());
>         publicKeyEncoded = new String(
>                 Base64.encodeBase64(byteOs.toByteArray()));
>         return "ssh-dss " + publicKeyEncoded + " " + user;
>     }
>     else{
>         throw new IllegalArgumentException(
>                 "Unknown public key encoding: " + publicKey.getAlgorithm());
>     }
> }
> ```

---

The @gotoalberto's code is implemented for RSA and DSA keys only. If you need other keys, you have to add them yourself.