# Create authorized keys from ECDSA public key

Tags: bouncycastle, public-key-encryption, openssh, ecdsa

I'm using Bouncy Castle API and I have ECPublicKey object but I'm not sure exactly how to construct a OpenSSH authorized key from there. I don't know what the format looks like. I'm thinking my solution would be similar to how it's done for RSA and DSA.. [Decoding RSA/DSA Public Key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5402769/8227972)

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The format of ECDSA keys is described in the [RFC5656](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5656#section-3.1):

In short:

> The "ecdsa-sha2-*" key formats all have the following encoding:
>
> ```
> string   "ecdsa-sha2-[identifier]"
> byte[n]  ecc_key_blob
> ```
>
> The ecc_key_blob value has the following specific encoding:
>
> ```
> string   [identifier]
> string   Q
> ```