# Kotlin bit shifting

Tags: kotlin, bit-shift

I want to convert the code if this answer to Kotlin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5402769/2735398

I pasted this into Intellij:

```
private int decodeInt() {
    return ((bytes[pos++] & 0xFF) << 24) | ((bytes[pos++] & 0xFF) << 16)
            | ((bytes[pos++] & 0xFF) << 8) | (bytes[pos++] & 0xFF);
}
```

Intellij asks if I want to convert it to Kotlin, when I do this is the output:

```
private fun decodeInt(): Int {
    return (bytes[pos++] and 0xFF shl 24 or (bytes[pos++] and 0xFF shl 16)
            or (bytes[pos++] and 0xFF shl 8) or (bytes[pos++] and 0xFF))
}
```

At all `0xFF` I get this error:

```
The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Byte
```

By appending `.toByte()` after it I was able to remove this error.

And at all shift left operations(`shl`) I get this error:

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 

@SinceKotlin @InlineOnly public infix inline fun BigInteger.shl(n: Int): BigInteger defined in kotlin
```

I wasn't able to solve this one...
I don't know a lot about bit shifting in Java/Kotlin...
What would be the working Kotlin code for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Convert explicitly like this: `0xFF.toByte()`

As a general rule, press Alt+Enter when you need more information about an error or a possible solution.

The shift left method takes an Int as parameter. So, same thing, convert to the right type.

```
(bytes[pos++] and 0xFF.toByte()).toInt() shl 24
```

Comment: This has 8 conversions. It works, but it can be done with just 4 conversions.

Comment: @Paul Hicks You're probably right. I'll counter your donwvote on the basis that I don't see how your answer is any worse and the person who downvoted didn't say what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

shl expects Int, not Byte. You need 0xFF to be an Int (which it is), so don't call `toByte()`. You need `(0xFF shl 24)` to be an Int, so don't convert that. You need `bytes[pos++]` to be an Int.. convert that!

```
return (((bytes[pos++].toInt() and (0xFF shl 24)) or
         (bytes[pos++].toInt() and (0xFF shl 16)) or
         (bytes[pos++].toInt() and (0xFF shl 8)) or
         (bytes[pos++].toInt() and 0xFF))
```

Comment: Or possibly even better.. change `bytes` to be an Int array rather than a Byte array. It will be faster in most cases, though obviously use more memory.

Answer (score 0):

you can create custom extensions like below.
If you use "and" from these extensions, shl will not cause problems.

```
infix fun Byte.and(mask: Int): Int = toInt() and mask
infix fun Short.and(mask: Int): Int = toInt() and mask
infix fun Int.and(mask: Long): Long = toLong() and mask
```